# Django: I want to recognize a hash url

Tags: python, django, web-services

I have a url like 
    `http://localhost/user/?hash={hash value generated}`

i need to configure urls.py so that any url of this form is recognized and does not give an error.

I currently wrote urls.py as

`url(r'^user/(?P<hash>\w+)/$', 'Myapp.views.createnewpass'),`

and this is giving a 404 error for a valid hash.

How can I correct this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, it should be clear to you that the regex does not match the URL: it's looking for URLs in the form /user/hash/, whereas you have /user/?hash=hash.

In any case, query parameters (those after the ?) do not get processed by urls.py, they are passed in request.GET. So your URLconf should just be `r'^user/$`.